# jQuery .text content from one table-cell to another each row

Tags: jquery, html

I have dynamic table with some rows. I try to get the ".tags"-td-content and write it to the ".tagsNew"-td in each row.

```
  <tr>
     <td class="td1">
        Date 1
     </td>
     <td class="td2">
        Text 1
        <div class="tags"><a href="http://home1.com">Row_1_Tag</a></div>
     </td>
     <td class="tagsNew">
     </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
     <td class="td1">
        Date 2
     </td>
     <td class="td2">
        Text 2
        <div class="tags"><a href="http://home2.com">Row_2_Tag</a></div>
     </td>
     <td class="tagsNew">
     </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
     <td class="td1">
        Date 3
     </td>
     <td class="td2">
        Text 3
        <div class="tags"><a href="http://home3.com">Row_3_Tag</a></div>
     </td>
     <td class="tagsNew">
     </td>
  </tr>

  ...
```

Desired result:

```
  <tr>
     <td class="td1">
        Date 1
     </td>
     <td class="td2">
        Text 2
        <div class="tags"><a href="http://home1.com">Row_1_Tag</a></div>
     </td>
     <td class="tagsNew">
         Row_1_Tag   /* needed */
     </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
     <td class="td1">
        Date 2
     </td>
     <td class="td2">
        Text 2
        <div class="tags"><a href="http://home2.com">Row_2_Tag</a></div>
     </td>
     <td class="tagsNew">
         Row_2_Tag   /* needed */
     </td>
  </tr>

  ...
```

This is my script:

```
<script>

function getTag(){

    row = $("tr");
    tagNeeded = $('tr .tags').text()

    $.each(row, function() {
        $('.tagsNew').text(tagNeeded);  
    });
}

</script>
```

The code works, but I need only the the .tags-content from the specific row.
The function pastes the content from all rows into the .tagsNew table-cell

This is happens with above code

```
<!-- Result with function getTag() -->
  <tr>
     <td class="td1">
        Date 1
     </td>
     <td class="td2">
        Text 1
        <div class="tags"><a href="http://home1.com">Row_1_Tag</a></div>
     </td>
     <td class="tagsNew">
         Row_1_Tag Row_2_Tag Row_3_Tag
     </td>
  </tr>
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to set relevant specific text:

```
$('.tagsNew').text(function(){
    return $(this).closest('tr').find('.tags').text();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.tags').each(function() {
  $this = $(this);
  $this.closest('td').next().text($this.text());
});
```

Note that this is strictly related to your current *exact* structure: it's not intended for a *general* use.